# Concurrently sorting many arrays with CUDA Thrust

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust

I need to sort `20+` arrays, already on the GPU, each of the same length, by the same keys. I can not use `sort_by_key()` directly since it sorts the keys as well (making them useless to sort the next array). Here is what I tried instead:

```
thrust::device_vector<int>  indices(N); 
thrust::sequence(indices.begin(),indices.end());
thrust::sort_by_key(keys.begin(),keys.end(),indices.begin());

thrust::gather(indices.begin(),indices.end(),a_01,a_01);
thrust::gather(indices.begin(),indices.end(),a_02,a_02);
...
thrust::gather(indices.begin(),indices.end(),a_20,a_20);
```

This does not seem to work since `gather()` expects a different array for the output than for the input, i.e. this works:

```
thrust::gather(indices.begin(),indices.end(),a_01,o_01);
...
```

However, I would prefer to not allocate `20+` extra arrays for this task. I know that there is a solution using a thrust::tuple, thrust::zip_iterator and thrust::sort_by_keys(), similiar to [here](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2011/06/27/thrust-compact-multiple-vectors-using-predicate/). However, I can only combine up to `10` arrays in a tuple, s.t. I would need to duplicate the key vector again. How would you tackle this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you really only need to allocate one extra array if you are OK with manipulating pointers to `device_vector` instead:

```
thrust::device_vector<int>  indices(N); 
thrust::sequence(indices.begin(),indices.end());
thrust::sort_by_key(keys.begin(),keys.end(),indices.begin());

thrust::device_vector<int> temp(N);
thrust::device_vector<int> *sorted = &temp;
thrust::device_vector<int> *pa_01 = &a_01;
thrust::device_vector<int> *pa_02 = &a_02;
...
thrust::device_vector<int> *pa_20 = &a_20;

thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), *pa_01, *sorted);
pa_01 = sorted; sorted = &a_01;
thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), *pa_02, *sorted);
pa_02 = sorted; sorted = &a_02;
...
thrust::gather(indices.begin(), indices.end(), *pa_20, *sorted);
pa_20 = sorted; sorted = &a_20;
```

Or something like that should work anyway.  You would need to fix it so the temp device vector is not automatically deallocated when it goes out of scope -- I suggest allocating the CUDA device pointers using cudaMalloc and then wrapping them with device_ptr instead of using automatic device_vectors.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your solution correctly (what is out? what do you need the temp vector for? Why do you set sorted to a_01 after pa_01 was sorted?). However, from what I can grasp the idea is to use only one additional vector and copy it's contents back after each sort. This is of course much better than my attempt (no idea what I was thinking, long day), but still, the full temp array needs to be copied back after each sort, which is rather costly...

Comment: There was a typo, corrected.  Those assignments are pointer assignments, not copies.  So there is no expensive copy.  You need at least one extra array for the reason you pointed out -- `thrust::gather` is performed out of place, not in place.  But after writing to the temp vector, you can assign it to pa_01, then use the input to the first gather as the output buffer for the next one, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I think that the classical way to sort multiple arrays is the so-called **back-to-back** approach which uses uses `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` two times. You need to create a *keys vector* such that elements within the same array have the same key. For example:

```
Elements: 10.5 4.3 -2.3 0. 55. 24. 66.
Keys:      0    0    0  1   1   1   1
```

In this case we have two arrays, the first with `3` elements and the second with `4` elements.

You first need to call `thrust::stable_sort_by_key` having the matrix values as the keys like

```
thrust::stable_sort_by_key(d_matrix.begin(),
                           d_matrix.end(),
                           d_keys.begin(),
                           thrust::less<float>());
```

After that, you have

```
Elements: -2.3 0 4.3 10.5 24. 55. 66.
Keys:       0  1  0    0   1   1   1
```

which means that the array elements are ordered, while the keys are not. Then you need a second to call `thrust::stable_sort_by_key`

```
thrust::stable_sort_by_key(d_keys.begin(),
                           d_keys.end(),
                           d_matrix.begin(),
                           thrust::less<int>());
```

so performing a sorting according to the keys. After that step, you have

```
Elements: -2.3 4.3 10.5 0 24. 55. 66.
Keys:       0   0   0   1  1   1   1
```

which is the final desired result.

Below, a full working example which considers the following problem: **separately order each row of a matrix**. This is a particular case in which all the arrays have the same length, but the approach works with arrays having possibly different lengths.

```
#include <cublas_v2.h>

#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/random.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

/**************************************************************/
/* CONVERT LINEAR INDEX TO ROW INDEX - NEEDED FOR APPROACH #1 */
/**************************************************************/
template <typename T>
struct linear_index_to_row_index : public thrust::unary_function<T,T> {

    T Ncols; // --- Number of columns

    __host__ __device__ linear_index_to_row_index(T Ncols) : Ncols(Ncols) {}

    __host__ __device__ T operator()(T i) { return i / Ncols; }
};

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    const int Nrows = 5;     // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 8;     // --- Number of columns

    // --- Random uniform integer distribution between 10 and 99
    thrust::default_random_engine rng;
    thrust::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(10, 99);

    // --- Matrix allocation and initialization
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_matrix(Nrows * Ncols);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < d_matrix.size(); i++) d_matrix[i] = (float)dist(rng);

    // --- Print result
    printf("Original matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    /*************************/
    /* BACK-TO-BACK APPROACH */
    /*************************/
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_keys(Nrows * Ncols);

    // --- Generate row indices
    thrust::transform(thrust::make_counting_iterator(0),
                      thrust::make_counting_iterator(Nrows*Ncols),
                      thrust::make_constant_iterator(Ncols),
                      d_keys.begin(),
                      thrust::divides<int>());

    // --- Back-to-back approach
    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(d_matrix.begin(),
                               d_matrix.end(),
                               d_keys.begin(),
                               thrust::less<float>());

    thrust::stable_sort_by_key(d_keys.begin(),
                               d_keys.end(),
                               d_matrix.begin(),
                               thrust::less<int>());

    // --- Print result
    printf("\n\nSorted matrix\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < Nrows; i++) {
        std::cout << "[ ";
        for(int j = 0; j < Ncols; j++)
            std::cout << d_matrix[i * Ncols + j] << " ";
        std::cout << "]\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```